How to NOT target sidebar
I added CSS to add a specific style of underlining of hyperlinks in posts. I managed to make it work so the CSS wouldn't affected headers or footers. However, it does affect links in my sidebar, which I don't want. Both text and images in sidebar with links get underlining now.
How can I either 1) change this CSS so it would only affect the text in the blog posts or 2) exclude the sidebar from this CSS?
body.single.single-post .site-content a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.4rem #EE841B8F
}

Live example: https://twoinrome.com/hidden-gems-in-rome/
I tried adding "not" to the css, but it didn't seem to work (or at least, not "my" way)

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.  See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Two things.
Your site is easy to read. But underlining hinders reading already.
Then I found a way to only aim at the a at .primary.
body.single.single-post .site-content .primary a {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.4rem #EE841B8F;
}

